# Laravel FormRequest - Handling Failure Response

Tags: xml, validation, laravel, laravel-5.1

If I inject the `FormRequest` into the Controller method, such as:

```
public function createTask(CreateTaskRequest $request)
{
    // ...
}
```

I can validate all the data inside the `CreateTaskRequest` as usual using the `rules()` method. But how can I handle the response myself when the validation fails? There are cases for our API where I want to return an XML response, so I need some sort of way to access the error bag and output all the errors in the XML response.

Comment: Instead of Request based validation, use Controller based (manual validation), Follow this link https://laravel.com/docs/5.1/validation#other-validation-approaches I Hope that will solve your problem

Answer (score 2, accepted):

On your `FormRequest` object, you can override the `response` method. This method is called when validation fails, and it is passed an array of the errors. To give you an idea of how it works, the built in method is shown below:

```
public function response(array $errors)
{
    if ($this->ajax() || $this->wantsJson()) {
        return new JsonResponse($errors, 422);
    }

    return $this->redirector->to($this->getRedirectUrl())
                                    ->withInput($this->except($this->dontFlash))
                                    ->withErrors($errors, $this->errorBag);
}
```

So, for your case, you'd want to override it to return your XML response:

```
public function response(array $errors)
{
    // shouldReturnXml and buildXmlResponse are just dummy function names.
    // you would need to implement their logic.

    // check conditions on whether to return xml or not
    if ($this->shouldReturnXml()) {
        // if you need xml, build it
        return $this->buildXmlResponse();
    }

    // if you don't need xml, just handle business as usual
    return parent::response($errors);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is some sample code..

**1)**

```
    $validateUser           = Validator::make(Input::all(), $rules);

    if($validateUser->fails()){            
        $errors = $validateUser->errors(); 
        return Redirect::back()->withErrors($errors)->withInput();
    }
```

**2)**

```
   $file = Input::file('upload_file');
   $input = array('upload_file' => $file);

   $rules = array('upload_file' => 'image|max:3072');
   $validator = Validator::make($input, $rules);

   $errorMessageBag - $validator->getMessageBag()->toArray();

   if ( $validator->fails() ){
     return Response::json(['status' => 'fail', 'message' => $errorMessageBag]);
   }
```